# Hubot on Ubuntu error: Type error bad argument

Tags: ubuntu, hubot

Installed Hubot on a clean latest Ubuntu desktop. First attempt at running Hubot results in this:

```
cd /opt/hubot && ./bin/hubot
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
[Wed Dec 24 2014 15:37:46 GMT-0500 (EST)] ERROR TypeError: Bad argument
  at Object.fs.fstat (fs.js:669:11)
  at onOpen (/opt/hubot/node_modules/readline-history/readline-history.js:62:12)
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Made sure to do an apt-get update to get latest.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing if you are like me you ended up running hubot as sudo the first time. That created a .hubot_history as root. You need to change that to your regular user so it can be written to.

```
sudo chown your_user ./.hubot_history
```

Good luck